# Creating a CMakeLists.txt with header and mains

Tags: makefile, cmake, header

I have divided my program in 3 folders: build, include, and src.

Build is where I want all the files created from the Makefile to go, include contains a "file.h", and src contains a "file.c" and "main.c".

I have written this in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)

project(Listas_interlazadas)

include_directories(${include})


add_executable(ejec
  src/main.c
  src/listas.c
  include/listas.h

)
```

Nonetheless, I believe I should somehow include the src folder. Also, how do I send all files to the build folder? From the terminal, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code need some minor reworks.

- The command include_directories must point to an valid path
- Add header files only in case they are not included in any of your source files

Assume the following structure of your project:

```
   project
     +--source
     |    +--CMakeLists.txt
     |    +--src
     |    |    +--main.c 
     |    |    +--listas.c 
     |    +--include
     |         +--listas.h     
     +--build
```

Reworked CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)

project(Listas_interlazadas)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(ejec
  src/main.c
  src/listas.c
)
```

Back to your questions:

- Add the sources: You already inserted the required source files. See `add_executable`.
- Copy sources to build folder: This is not necessary.

To build your project, you have to run cmake and make (or nmake on windows).

Steps:

1. Open a command shell
2. Move to the build folder
3. Run: cmake ../source
4. Run: make

[Some important parts of a CMakeLists.txt](http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/cmake/cmake_qmake_to_cmake.html)

Comment: Listing headers in `add_executable` *does* make sense, f.i. to let your IDE know that they are part of your project.

Comment: You are right. But this was not requested by OP and it depends from the IDE. E.g. QtCreator does not require it.